# How can this "Bloody Brain" cocktail be made without alcohol?

Tags: substitutions, alcohol, cocktails

I found this recipe for a Halloween cocktail known as a "Bloody brain", [here's a link](http://folkinz.tumblr.com/post/222293315/i-was-looking-up-recipes-for-pumpkin-martinis-i), and I was wondering how I would go about making a non-alcoholic version.

The recipe involves strings of Bailey's Irish Cream that do not mix properly and form tendrils that bunch together and look like a brain. I would like to know how to achieve the same effect with no alcohol.

Comment: Your original question read like a recipe request, which is [off-topic](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the things in this are very easy to substitute.

Roses lime juice is sweet and non-alcoholic (and can be found in most supermarkets).

You can easily sub in heavy cream for Baileys: they don't taste the same, but chemically they react about the same.

Grenadine is just a pomegranate juice simple syrup. No alcohol there at all.

The only question is what you want to sub for the strawberry vodka. Some kind of soda, most likely. It's a question of taste. It won't be easy to get something that is both fruity and clear, but you might try white cranberry juice, or white grape juice.

Comment: That sounds like it would work... I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: I do not suggest carbonated replacement for vodka myself.

Comment: @Chris: Yea, it sounded blech. But I couldn't come up with anything that was clear and fruit-flavored. The only things I saw were "Pill Glide" (http://www.northstarnutritionals.com/p/Pill_Glide.htm) and the Pur water-filter with the strawberry flavor option (http://www.purwater.com/pur-products/flavor-options/).

Comment: I second the white grape juice suggestion. Even "strawberry-flavored" fruit juice or most 100% fruit juice flavored drinks for kids which are normally about 80-90% white grape, apple or pear juice anyhow regardless of what flavor they are called - just look at the ingredients -- this is because those lighter flavored filler juices are the cheapest.

Comment: For example, the Minute Maid strawberry flavor 100% juice drink is apple, pear, and grape juice with less than 2% actual strawberry juice.

Answer (score 4):

The basic principle relies on the acid (lime) and alcohol curdling the cream in the shot. You could do something similar using cream and any acid. I'm assuming you're making this for kids (I cannot imagine any adult drinking something this gross without the benefit of an alcoholic buzz)? You could try cream and apple juice, might be acidic enough.

Or you could go full on crazy with it. At a *wild* guess, you could make cream 'noodles' using liquid nitrogen, then drop the noodles into a warm alginate bath. The alginate should react with the calcium in the cream to encapsulate the noodles, and the freezing should allow them to maintain their shape while the chemical reaction takes place. Then add to whatever liquid you desire. Alternate options would include setting noodles with agar or gelatine mixed with cream, then placing into $liquid that has had xanthan gum added to suspend the noodles.